# Echo html code from php to html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server

I'm working on my own project for a music site and i'm blocked on a situation. Right now i'm working on the playlist and i want to echo from `php`(i'm working with `odbc` connection) on html, but it's not putting all the data, only the first row, and i want all the data from `database` to be echo in the playlist.

I tried to make an echo statement in `php` which to send row by row with html code.

This is my **PHP**:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(6);

include("connect.php");
include("checklogin.php");

$username   = $_SESSION['username']; 
//echo $username;

  $sql="select name from [YourTube].[dbo].[yt_url] 
                where username='$user_check'";

    $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

//echo $sql;


while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
  $name = odbc_result($rs, 1);
  //print("$name\n");
}

?>
```

And i have tried to put something like this in php>>

```
 <?php if($rs) { ?>

      <li class="list_item selected">
              <div class="title" action="../php/songs.php"><?php echo 
  odbc_result($rs, 1)?></div>
           </li>

<?php } ?>
```

And the result is just the first row from `database`, but if i print $name it's showing all the rows.

The **html code** for playlist:

```
<div class="list_wrapper">
  <ul class="list"> 
    <li class="list_item selected"> 
      <div class="info"> 
        <div class="title" action="../php/songs.php"><?php echo 
odbc_result($rs, 1)?></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And like i said, this code on `html` it's showing only one row in playlist, not all of them. And i'm thinking to do something like echo from `php` in html code for every row something like this:

```
<li class="list_item selected"> 
      <div class="info"> 
        <div class="title" action="../php/songs.php"><?php echo 
odbc_result($rs, 1)?></div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Can someone help me with this? I'm working on this thing for some days and i can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you in advance!
Bogdan

Comment: why use $name = odbc_result($rs, 1);you should use array instead of string.if you not ,The last value will cover the previous value

Comment: @long i will try to do that :-? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply `while()` inside `if()` like below:-

```
<?php if($rs) { 
    while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
?>

    <li class="list_item selected">
        <div class="title" action="../php/songs.php"><?php echo odbc_result($rs, 1)?></div>
    </li>

<?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: This answer is better then mine! Deleted my answer. +1

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working! Not exactly on what i was thinking, but this result is very good. Thank you again!